# Focus back to datagrid column after editing in flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3

How can I get back the focus to the column after editing datagrid by Keypress.Enter, so that I can move to another column using arrow keys. Now its stuck in the edited cell and I cant move to another column.

Thanks,
Rej

Answer (score 0):

Use focusManager to setup focus of cell which should be presented inside of event.currentTarget

read next articles:

http://www.vaishalimistry.com/2005/12/15/set-focus-on-a-cell-in-datagrid-in-flex-20/

http://www.axelscript.com/2008/02/20/using-the-focusmanager-in-flex/

Comment: After editing,inside the itemeditend event I set focusManager.setFocus(datagrid), but this calls the datagrid edit mode agian for the selected cell. please advice

Comment: it will be great to see your code you are referencing, but are you asking to set Render Mode to non editable after focus setting back?